# Failed to run python flask app (404, 405 response code)

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

Doing 2nd CS50 project and the first thing I have to do is to create an index.html page where I have to type in a username and it'll displayed. I have to do it using SocketIO to make other users be able to see it too.

When I run my Flask app and go the page I'm getting the following text in my console:

```
flask run
 * Serving Flask-SocketIO app "main.py"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 399-480-796
127.0.0.1 - - [2018-08-12 05:17:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1123 0.008075
127.0.0.1 - - [2018-08-12 05:17:55] "GET /index.js HTTP/1.1" 404 342 0.000796
127.0.0.1 - - [2018-08-12 05:17:55] "GET /static/index.js HTTP/1.1" 404 342 0.000821
127.0.0.1 - - [2018-08-12 05:17:55] "GET /static/index.js HTTP/1.1" 404 342 0.003149
```

But when I press my "Enter" button it fails with 'Method Not Allowed' and what I see in my console is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [2018-08-12 05:18:01] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 323 0.003737
```

project_folder/main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = 'dev'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on("new user")
def new(data):
    username = data["username"]
    emit('plus user', {'username': username}, broadcast=True)
```

project_folder/templates/layout.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='index.js'></script>
    <script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      {% block body %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

project_folder/templates/index.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
  Sign In
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

  <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method='post'>

    <h1>Hi! In this chat room you can be whoever you want.</h1>
    <h2>The only thing I ask you is to tell me the name I'll be calling you.</h2>
    <h3>You don't have to tell me your real name.</h3>
    <h4>Enjoy.</h4>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name='username' autofocus placeholder="Username">
    </div>

    <div class="formgroup">
      <button id='newuser' class='btn btn-primary' data-new='username'>Enter</button>
    </div>

    <ul id="users"></ul>
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

project_folder/templates/index.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // connect to websocket
  var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ":" + location.port);

  // when connected, configure buttons
  socket.on('connect', () => {

    document.querySelector('#newuser').onclick = () => {
      const username = newuser.dataset.new;
      socket.emit('new user', {'username': username})
    };
  });

});

// When a new user has registered , add to the ul
socket.on('plus user', data => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = data.username;
  document.querySelector('#users').append(li);
});
```

It's almost the same task and I took like 90% of the code from the lecture video but it doesn't wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Layout.html

You are Routing Index.Js to wrong Folder, either replace static with template as done below

```
<script src='{{ url_for('templates', filename='index.js') }}'></script>
```

Or create a new folder **static** in the root directory,i.e. **project_folder** if you want to use:

```
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}'></script>
```

Generally the second way is preferred.

Comment: I tried the first way and it causes an error 'BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'templates' with values ['filename']. Did you mean 'static' instead?' So I have a question about the 2nd way. If I create a folder named 'static' and put here 'index.js' file how can I refer to it from my layout.html file?

Comment: Oh yeah! i forget if you try to change the static directory then you need to tell to the Flask Configuration that you are going to use some other Folder which you can do by `app["STATIC_FOLDER"]="YourFolderName" `. I Guess But not that much sure, You have to just place the `<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}'></script>` in the layout.html, remaining works will be done by url_for function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your routing is at fault here. Your form is submitting to URL pattern of 'index' but your routing only handles the '/' route.

Change

```
@app.route("/")
```

to following in main.py:

```
@app.route("/index")
```

Comment: I guess it's fine because if I change the routing I get this error: "

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."